# Unshelving to new branch using TFS Power Tools 2015 merges content into source, not target

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, merge, tfs-power-tools

I ran the command `tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:$/Dev/MyBranch /target:$/Main` from the root project folder containing all branches, taking care to undo all pending changes—both included and excluded—in the source and target branches first. As expected I saw a dialog asking me to select a shelveset, then a rundown of files from the selected shelveset in my VS Developer Command Prompt:

```
edit: file1.js
edit: file2.js
add: file3.js
add: file4.js
add: file5.html
edit: file6.css
...
```

The strange thing was that the files merged back into my source branch (Dev\MyBranch) rather than into my target branch (Main). After a `tfpt unshelve /undo` of the desired shelveset I tried switching the paths for the target and source branches, i.e. `tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:$/Main /target:$/Dev/MyBranch` but it had the same result. I also tried running the command from \Dev\MyBranch and \Main instead of the root project folder but no matter what I did the shelveset always merged into the dev branch I originally shelved it from. I wasn't able to find any other cases of this issue by searching and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Can you provide the detail steps to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

From my test in TFS 2015, after running `tfpt unshelve /migrate` command, the shelvesets will be added to the target path. Please check my command:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you are not able to see the shelvesets added to the target path as I highlighted?

Comment: As I explained in the original question the shelved files are added to the source path when I run the command, not the target path.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side, are you able to share a screenshot which is similar to mine?